# What does OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY (OP_CSV) do?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, checksequenceverify

Some people have suggested repurposing OP_NOP3 as a new opcode, OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY.

What would the new opcode do? Why is it useful? Can't the signer choose the sequence field when they sign?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY` (a.k.a `OP_RELATIVECHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY`) can do **relative lock times** (used for sidechains and lightning).

It basically checks, if an input's sequence number is smaller than the sequence threshold (1 << 31 = 2147483648), and if so, it will compare the `nLockTime` against the sequence number of the input.

More info:

- https://github.com/ElementsProject/elementsproject.github.io/tree/master#relative-lock-time
- https://github.com/maaku/bitcoin/commit/fd9864c3a3c6f2942bc0775c6c725aa379f9d616
- https://lightning.network/lightning-network-paper.pdf

Comment: OP_CSV (BIP112) only constrains the nSequence value. The comparison of nSequence against time happens independently of OP_CSV's usage (BIP68).